# Using Tor with Tails only as a client

Tags: tor

I'm running a VM with Tails to use the Tor network with the Tor browser. I've heard about the risk of getting an exit-node myself and the tipp to deactivate this option.

Where can I do this in tails?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Tails it acts purely as a client. No need do deactivate something. Everything else would violate user expectations and threaten your privacy.